# Error (AssertionError: "undefined" === "function") when deploying Meteor app

Tags: node.js, meteor, digital-ocean

I have a Digital Ocean server running Ubuntu 14.04 and a Mac from which I deploy.

```
mupx deploy
```

has always worked fine. Now I have added 2 packages and updated to Meteor 1.4. and I get this error:

```
[139.59.242.839] - Uploading bundle
[139.59.242.839] - Uploading bundle: SUCCESS
[139.59.242.839] - Sending environment variables
[139.59.242.839] - Sending environment variables: SUCCESS
[139.59.242.839] - Initializing start script
[139.59.242.839] - Initializing start script: SUCCESS
[139.59.242.839] - Invoking deployment process
[139.59.242.839] - Invoking deployment process: SUCCESS
[139.59.242.839] - Verifying deployment
[139.59.242.839] x Verifying deployment: FAILED

-----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
npm WARN cannot run in wd meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 node npm-rebuild.js (wd=/bundle/bundle/programs/server)
=> Starting meteor app on port:80

assert.js:93
  throw new assert.AssertionError({
        ^
AssertionError: "undefined" === "function"
    at wrapPathFunction (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:77:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:108:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:9:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)

=> Redeploying previous version of the app
```

Thus I have downgraded meteor and removed the packages. Then upgraded metor again. Nothing helped. The worst part of this is that although it says it would redeploy the previous version, my app is down now.
I have googled around and apparently a bunch of people have a similar problem but always with a slightly different error. I tried to update nodejs with

```
npm update mupx -g
```

and

```
mupx setup
```

unfortunately nothing helped. Any hints are more than welcome :)`

Comment: I have the same problem, any solution yet? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a "temporary" solution.

Check the answers of @humbertocruz inside this link-> https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/issues/1091

Change start.sh file of mupx (or mup) and change pull docker image.

Answer (score 1):

You may have this issue if you are not using Node 4.4.7.
Check out this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7521).

Answer (score 1):

So after a lot of struggling I ended up concluding that the problem was the newest Meteor version (1.4) which was incompatible with mupx or at least resulted in some problems. I downgraded the app (which was a hassle) and am considering to change from mupx to another package to deploy to the server before upgrading Meteor again. (not sure how to do this as I am new to meteor so sorry for the brief description)

Comment: Think that better solution is update your start.sh file because downgrade to a minor Meteor version is not the best option... But, you are free to decide which is the best option for you :)

Comment: how should I change it? Yes I can definitively confirm that downgrading is not a good option. Just the only I could find at that moment :P